# How do you configure a Component's underlying layer?

Tags: ios, componentkit

For example: how might you set the border width for a `CKButtonComponent`? When using views directly, you would specify it like this:

`view.layer.borderWidth = xx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CKComponentViewAttribute::LayerAttribute(@selector(setBorderWidth:))`](https://github.com/facebook/componentkit/blob/master/ComponentKit/Core/CKComponentViewAttribute.h#L73).